# Need Help In Drawing

Tags: c#

Following is my code. i am trying to draw line, filled rectangle, etc.....

Problem is that, lets suppose i draw a line but when i try to draw an other line first drawn line disappears. so i want help that i'll be able to draw multiple shapes on a form and first draw lines don't disappears.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace finalPaint
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
        Rectangle rect;
        Point first;
        Point last;
        string op;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                points.Add(e.Location);
                rect = new Rectangle(rect.Left, rect.Top, e.X - rect.Left, e.Y - rect.Top);
                last = e.Location;
                this.Invalidate();
                this.Update();
            }
        }
        private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (op)
            {
                case "toolStripButton1":
                    {
                         if (points.Count > 2)
                         {
                             e.Graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Black, points.ToArray());

                         }
                    }
                        break;
                case "toolStripButton2":
                        {
                            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
                            {
                                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
                            }
                        }
                        break;

                case "toolStripButton3":
                        {
                            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
                            e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, first, last);
                            this.Update();

                        }
                        break;

                case "toolStripButton4":
                        {
                            using (SolidBrush pen = new SolidBrush(Color.Red))
                            {
                                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(pen, rect);
                            }
                        }
                        break;

                case "toolStripButton5":
                        {
                            using (SolidBrush pen = new SolidBrush(Color.Red))
                            {
                                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(pen, rect);
                            }
                        }
                        break;

                case "toolStripButton6":
                        {
                            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red,2))
                            {
                                e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, rect);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            rect = new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 0, 0);
            first = e.Location;
            this.Invalidate();
        }

        private void toolStrip1_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void selectedButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (ToolStripButton btn in toolStrip1.Items)
            {
                btn.Checked = false;
            }

            ToolStripButton btnClicked = sender as ToolStripButton;
            btnClicked.Checked = true;
            op = btnClicked.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend you using the `.Tag` property for each control, and the `sender` object in the event handler in order to figure out who sent the message.

Answer (score 6):

On each Paint event, you need to paint all of the objects you want on the screen.  You are not just painting on top of what is already there.  You are repainting the entire scene.

The reason for this is that your control may be obscured from view at some point, and Windows will repaint it when it is revealed again.

If you want to keep a memory of all the the objects, you need to store them in your code.  Since each object is different (lines, rectangles, ellipses) you will want to store them in a manner that lets you differentiate.  You could create classes like this:

```
public class DrawingShape
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DrawingShapeType Type { get; set; }
    // other shared properties

    public virtual void Draw(Graphics g)
    {
    }
}

public class DrawingRectangle : DrawingShape
{
    public DrawingRectangle()
    {
        Name = "Rectangle";
        Type = DrawingShapeType.Rectangle;
    }

    public override void Draw(Graphics g)
    {
        // draw this shape
    }
}

public enum DrawingShapeType
{
    Rectangle,
    Ellipse,
    Line,
}
```

Then you can just store all your objects in a List.  The order of the items in the list is your z-order, so you add items to the list and you enumerate through the list in your Paint event and draw each one differently depending on the type.

From here you can store pen and brush information in the class and other info.  Your Paint event can tell each class to paint itself and it doesn't need to know which type they are.

Answer (score 1):

You need a possibility to store all your shapes, in order to draw them all in the `Paint` event, since the background of the form is repainted before each call to `Paint`. Let us define a base class from which we will derive all the shapes

```
abstract class Shape
{
    public abstract void Paint(PaintEventArgs e);
    public abstract void UpdateShape(Point newLocation);
}
```

Here we declare the abstract methods `Paint` and `UpdateShape` that we will have to override in the derived classes. `UpdateShape` will be called in `MouseMove`.

Let us start with the freeform line

```
class FreeformLine : Shape
{
    private List<Point> _points = new List<Point>();

    public FreeformLine(Point startLocation)
    {
        _points.Add(startLocation);
    }

    public override void Paint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_points.Count >= 2) {
            e.Graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Black, _points.ToArray());
        }
    }

    public override void UpdateShape(Point newLocation)
    {
        const int minDist = 3;

        // Add new point only if it has a minimal distance from the last one.
        // This creates a smoother line.
        Point last = _points[_points.Count - 1];
        if (Math.Abs(newLocation.X - last.X) >= minDist ||
            Math.Abs(newLocation.Y - last.Y) >= minDist)
        {
            _points.Add(newLocation);
        }
    }
}
```

Here we need a list of points. In the constructor, we pass the first point. The `Paint` method just executes the paint logic that you had already defined and the `UpdateShape` method adds new points to our points list.

The straight line works in a very similar way, but defines only the first and the last point.

```
class StraightLine : Shape
{
    private Point _first;
    private Point _last;

    public StraightLine(Point startLocation)
    {
        _first = startLocation;
    }

    public override void Paint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_last.IsEmpty) {
            Pen pen2 = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen2, _first, _last);
        }
    }

    public override void UpdateShape(Point newLocation)
    {
        _last = newLocation;
    }
}
```

We define only one rectangle class and add a variable in order to remember if the shape is filled or not.

```
class RectangleShape : Shape
{
    protected bool _filled;
    protected Rectangle _rect;
    protected Point _start;

    public RectangleShape(Point startLocation, bool filled)
    {
        _start = startLocation;
        _rect = new Rectangle(startLocation.X, startLocation.Y, 0, 0);
        _filled = filled;
    }

    public override void Paint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_filled) {
            using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red)) {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, _rect);
            }
        } else {
            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2)) {
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, _rect);
            }
        }
    }

    public override void UpdateShape(Point newLocation)
    {
        int x = Math.Min(_start.X, newLocation.X);
        int y = Math.Min(_start.Y, newLocation.Y);
        int width = Math.Abs(newLocation.X - _start.X);
        int height = Math.Abs(newLocation.Y - _start.Y);
        _rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```

Finally, we declare the ellipse class. Since this one uses a rectangle as well, we just derive it from our rectangle class.

```
class Ellipse : RectangleShape
{
    public Ellipse(Point startLocation, bool filled)
        : base(startLocation, filled)
    {
    }

    public override void Paint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_filled) {
            using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red)) {
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(brush, _rect);
            }
        } else {
            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2)) {
                e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, _rect);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here we only override the `Paint` method. All the rectangle update logic remains the same.

---

Now to the form. Here we declare the global variables

```
List<Shape> _shapes = new List<Shape>();
Shape _lastShape;
string op;
```

In the mouse down event we create a new shape and add it to the list like this

```
private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    switch (op) {
        case "toolStripButton1":
            _lastShape = new FreeformLine(e.Location);
            break;
        case "toolStripButton2":
            _lastShape = new RectangleShape(e.Location, false);
            break;
        case "toolStripButton3":
            _lastShape = new StraightLine(e.Location);
            break;
        case "toolStripButton4":
            _lastShape = new RectangleShape(e.Location, true);
            break;
        case "toolStripButton5":
            _lastShape = new Ellipse(e.Location, true);
            break;
        case "toolStripButton6":
            _lastShape = new Ellipse(e.Location, false);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    _shapes.Add(_lastShape);
    Refresh();
}
```

In the MouseMove we update the last shape like this

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && _lastShape != null) {
        _lastShape.UpdateShape(e.Location);
        this.Refresh();
    }
}
```

The `Paint` method is now much simpler

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Shape shape in _shapes) {
        shape.Paint(e);
    }
}
```

---

Note that we do all the shape specific things in the shape classes, instead of doing them in the form. The only place in the form where have to care about the different shapes, is where we create the different shapes. This is a typical object-oriented approach. It is easier to maintain and to extend. You could add new shapes, with only a minimum changes in the form itself.

Comment: I added some logic in the freeform lines to smoothen the lines a bit. The rectangles and ellipses can now be drawn to the left and to the top of the starting point. The code is tested and runs like a marvel.